How to get the current logged in users information on Web App API Integration React JS?
I am currently Integrating Web App API integration with React JS.
I am authenticating a user using this link https://${config.sfmc.tenantId}.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${config.sfmc.clientId}&redirect_uri=${config.sfmc.redirectUri} to get the code and pass the code on the OAuth2 or /v2/token endpoint to get access token
To authenticate the user, the user must be logged in on the other tab on sfmc, and my react application is on the other tab also.
Is it possible to get the currently logged in user information or the user that my app authenticated? I want to get the userid, username, useremail on my react js application
